# Creating a GORM custom data type, how to get context in scan?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to write a Gorm custom data type: https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html

```golang
type MyDataType struct {}

func (f *MyDataType) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    //
}

func (f MyDataType) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    //
}
```

For some reasons, I need to access context in `Scan` or to be able to retrieve field tags.

Is there a way to do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Value are based on user space which you may need to change the code to be looks like :

```golang
type MyDataType struct {}

func (f *MyDataType) Scan(context context.Context, value interface{}) error {
    // proceed the context right there
}

func (f MyDataType) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    //
}
```

Comment: The function "Scan" need as first parameter the context.Context

func (f *MyDataType) Scan(context context.Context, value interface{})

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What context you need to access?

Scan(...) is used to translate the database raw data into your custom fieldtype. You should know the format.

Value() is the other way around, it converts your custom field into whatever should be placed in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change params of `func Scan` or `func Value` as trying to do it will break `MyDataType`'s `sql.Scanner` and `sql.Valuer` implementation.

It can be done by embedding `context.Context` inside `MyDataType`.

```golang
type MyDataType struct {
    context.Context
}

func (f *MyDataType) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "key", value)
    f.Context = ctx
    return nil
}

func (f MyDataType) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    value := f.Context.Value("key")
    return value, nil
}
```